# Ĉu oni povas uzi la verbon "esti" kiel "konsisti el"?

Tags: word-usage

Mi legis tiun frazon:

> Mia teamo estis ses homoj.

Sed pli ofte, oni skribas:

> Mia teamo konsistis el ses homoj

Do mi ne certas pri la ĝusteco de la unua frazo. Ĉu ĝi estas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mi ne vidas ion ajn kritikindan ĉi tie.

- *Unu tago estas dudek kvar horoj.*
- *Unu kilometro estas mil metroj.*

Answer (score 1):

Laŭ miaj legitaj, mi trovas *esti el* pli ofte ke *konsisti el*. Tial mi dirus "*Mia teamo estis el ses homoj*". Mi preferas *konsisti el*, tamen...